# Does shooting explosives lower your accuracy?

Tags: sniper-elite-4

I haven't been able to find an answer online and I'm confused testing it out myself and was wondering if anyone else knew/had any information.

**Does shooting explosives such as oil drums or trucks lower your accuracy stat?**

If I shoot someone, and the bullet connects it counts as a hit (AFAIK), but if you hit nothing, your accuracy would go down. So does shooting non enemy troops (but can still grant you kills or XP) go against your accuracy statistic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I decided to try out my test as I said in the comments.

My first game, I shot and killed a soldier and then shot and blew up and explosive *that also killed someone*.  I then let someone kill me, and the game stats said **100% accuracy**.

I then restarted the game, and blew up the same explosive as before, but without killing anyone, and then died.  My accuracy was **again 100%.**  It even recorded a distance for the "Longest Shot" statistic for blowing up just the explosive.  There was no experience given for blowing up just the explosive, nor did it tell me (in game) the distance of the shot.  But, it does seem to impact accuracy.

One final test I decided to do was blow up the same explosive, shoot a random shot off into the distance, and then die.  My accuracy for this round **was 50%**, as expected.

So I conclude that shooting explosives do count towards accuracy, and so long as you actually blow it up, whether it kills someone or not, it will still count as a "good" shot.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for testing all the different scenarios. When I said non troops that earn XP I mostly meant trucks/other vehicles that you can blow up.

Comment: @n_palum right. I didn't test shooting a truck, but I imagine that would count towards accuracy as well.

Comment: I imagine it would and it seems to be, especially considering you're given XP and a distance stat to the shot same as a soldier.